# Eloquent conditional where filter

Tags: laravel, eloquent

If I have a variable that is optional, and I only want to have it search on it if it is defined, I know that I can do this, but is there a way to define the function elsewhere, so I don't need to rewrite the same anonymous function over and over again? Or are the any other good alternatives to going about solving this problem?

```
.......->where(function($query) use ($gender){
            if ($gender) {
                $query->where('gender', '=', $gender);
            }
            })->get();
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could use a [dynamic scope](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#query-scopes)

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    public function scopeGender($query, $gender)
    {
        if ($gender) {
           return $query->whereGender($gender);
        }
        return $query;
    }
}
```

Then throughout your application

```
...->gender($gender)->get();
```

Answer (score 58):

Since Laravel 5.2.27, you can use [conditional clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#conditional-clauses)

For example:

```
->when($gender, function($query) use ($gender) {
        return $query->where('gender', '=', $gender);
      })
->get();
```

Comment: You are missing a return in front of  `$query->where('gender', '=', $gender);`

Comment: From Laravel 6, the closure function takes a second parameter, which provides the value that the `when` matched as *truthy*. So here `$gender` could be any expression, and the `use ($gender)` can be removed, to give: `->when(<expression>, function($query, $genderExpression) {...});`