# How to check the column before executing the query in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, where-clause, laravel-query-builder

Like the title of the question, I want to check a column in my table before executing the query in Laravel, such as checking if the "department" field is null then executing a query, if the positions "field" is null then executing a query. I want to check the column in the table is null, not data variable.

```
 DB::table('tasks')
   ->when('to_departments is not null and to_positions is null', function($query) use ($user){
     $query->whereRaw('find_in_set('.$user->department.',to_departments)');
   })
   ->when('to_positions is not null and to_department is null', function($query) use ($user){
     $query->whereRaw('find_in_set('.$user->position.',to_positions)');
   })
   ->orderBy('id','desc')
   ->get();
   // with to_departments, to_positions is columns in table
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eloquent conditional where filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26750285/eloquent-conditional-where-filter)

Answer (score 0):

you can use laravel query builder `when` method

```
DB::table('tasks')
  ->when($condition, function($query) use ($user){
         $query->where('position', $user->position)
     })
 .....
  ->orderBy('id','desc')
  ->get();
```

the anonymous function will get executed when the `$condition` is truthy.
Its called [Conditional Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#conditional-clauses)

Comment: hi :( , i'm new so it's hard to understand, i tried to replace $condition to "department is null"  string (if column null), but it understood the "department is null" string = true and always executed Can you help me again?

Comment: try posting the code sample you wrote, with exact condition

Comment: I corrected my question, important is how to check null columns before query execution

Comment: I think you have got confused about what I said. Actually, the `$condition` is not an SQL query, rather its a PHP conditional expression. We don't know what your table structure looks like, so we don't know how neither `to_departments` nor `to_positions` does look like or in which table they are. maybe you need to post more info.